# HTACCESS 301 Redirects with Variables

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am not even sure this is possible but due to a site structure change, we need an urgent change, which is either a ReWriteCond or another site change. There would be too many url's to 301 one by one to do this by hand. (thousands).

The site had a structure with filtering such as:

http://www.site.com/?brand=123

this could be filtered even further, so it *could* be site.com/?brand=123&color=49&size=57 etc etc etc (could be even longer)

Without knowing a ton of code, is it possible to place site.com/?***** into a variable

and 301 redirect those variables to site.com/all/?***** regardless of how long the filtering was?

Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually very simple to do using a single `RewriteRule` (although you can restrict the redirection based on the domain too by adding a `RewriteCond`).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?example\.com
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/all/ [QSA,R=301]
```

This will do the redirect, and should add the query string to the end of the redirected URL:

```
http://www.example.com/?brand=123&color=red
  =>  http://example.com/all/?brand=123&color=red

http://example.com/?brand=123&color=red&size=colin
  =>  http://example.com/all/?brand=123&color=red&size=colin
```

Note however that as we're matching an empty path (the `^$` in the rule), it will not redirect any requests that are already in `/all`... or anything else for that matter:

```
http://example.com/all/?brand=123      : not redirected
http://example.com/index.php?brand=123 : not redirected
```

If you also want to redirect if the requested URL is to an index file (I'll use index.php as an example), you would do the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?example\.com
RewriteRule ^(index.php)?$ http://example.com/all/ [QSA,R=301]
```

Of course, you should replace "example.com" with your own domain name wherever you see it.

**Edit**: I've added an additional `RewriteCond`, which will mean that the rewrite will only occur if a query string is passed on the URL.

Comment: I used this: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?site\.com
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.site.com/all-products [QSA,R=301] and it worked, however, I couldn't goto the homepage as it would redirect me to site.com/all-products

Comment: Ah, so you only want the rewrite if there is a query_string (the `?brand=123...` part)? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hey icabod, I have another one if you fancy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820228/301-redirect-rewrites-with-patterns

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (?!^all/)^(.*)$ /all/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```