# 301 Redirect/Rewrites with Patterns

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I know using the power of regex, I can reduce my 301's into a few lines. However, I do not have the brain power for it.

Basically our links went from:

http://www.site.com/collection/womens-active (this can also have ?brand=123 queries attached to the end)

To:

http://www.site.com/collection/active

"womens-" is the changed part.

A simple 301 works perfectly, even with queries, but there is about 100 lines for this in htaccess.

With Regex, can we reduce this to a few lines?

Comment: I think you should provide to which file you want to rewrite. Also are you sure you want to redirect ?

Comment: So what have you tried to this point?

Comment: By these two comments, I guess I haven't made myself clear. As of today, I have a list in the hundreds of: Redirect 301 /collection/womens-active http://www.site.com/collection/active   --- this is fine and dandy, I figured there was a way to condense all the lines into a rewrite/cond with regex that would be able to remove that "womens-".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `RedirectMatch` instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/collection/([^/-]+)-active/(.*)$ /collection/active/$2
```

Assuming by the "is the changed part", you mean there could be anything where it says "womens-".

---

EDIT: Since it's the other way around, just swap the regex grouping and the "womens-":

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/collection/womens-([^/-]+)/(.*)$ /collection/$1/$2
```

Comment: I think this is close, but 'active' is a 'variable' (my wording) depending on the page. the constant that need to be removed is 'womens-' if link starts with /collection/